# CMake does not find Windows SDK 8.1

Tags: winapi, cmake

I am trying to download a C program called fluidsynth (https://sourceforge.net/p/fluidsynth) so that I can later install python bindings and use it in some code.

I installed CMake and Visual Studio. From the VS command line (as an administrator) I gave the command `cmake c:\path\to\fluidsynth`. I got a few errors:

1. In the command line, I got No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
2. In the CMake error log it says `Build FAILED` Then:

   ```
    error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. 
    Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the 
    SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking
    the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". 
    [C:\Users\user\Desktop\fluidsynth-1.1.6\CMakeFiles\3.4.3\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]
   ```

This error persists even after upgrading my Windows SDK.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2015? Visual Studio 2015 doesn't have C/C++ support by default. You need to select it during installation.

Comment: @RjOllos
Is there any way to resolve it without re-installation?

Comment: You can modify the installation in _Add or remove programs_. It might allow you to install additional features without re-running the installer.

Answer (score -8):

1.- Visual Basic?? CMake doesn't have native support for VB.
2.- If you are going to use CMake, you must be ensure that Win SDK is propertly registered its paths.
3.- Once is done, you only need to run, from the directory you extracted the files, the following command: `cmake .` if you still get errors, then something is not correctly registered nor installed. That wouldn't be cmake fault.

Comment: This answer isn't really useful. If something isn't registered properly, how would one find that out, and could it be fixed?

Comment: Hello @jPlatte, when you are going to develop you can't just start "type" code, you need to setup your environment so you can compile/link propertly...Agree with me? If you don't get informed WELL about how to do this, the tools you need on the way and you run into problems..is not my fault that you missed that part and for the worst...Is not my problem that you don't know how even use your PC in terms of developing. The anwser or possible answer is there...now how much do you know or willing to know is up to the developer.

Comment: There's no need to insult me. Maybe I wasn't clear enough though: I have the Windows SDK 8.1 installed. I also restarted afterwards. I'm still getting this error (from CMake and VS itself when trying to build any project). I assumed that this was the original problem as well, but after re-reading, I'm not sure anymore. What I'm trying to say is that your step 2 (the important part) isn't very useful because it lacks details of how to "ensure that Win SDK is properly registered".

Comment: I didn't mean to insult you. But, are you the same author of the post? Becuase the author is user2192778 with rep of 38 and you are jPlatte with rep of 384. Seems that you and I know the idiomatic of programing ;)

Comment: No, I didn't create this question, I just asked for clarification of 2., because I have the same problem, with Win SDK 8.1 being installed. I'll try to re-run the Visual Studio installer tomorrow, maybe that will help. Could be that it didn't like the Win SDK being installed seperately.

Comment: Oh, ok..I don't have VS or windows..but, I remember that VS installation copies in the start menu folder of VS a setup batch file to automatic register the need it paths. See if you have it.